# Overhead data when writing to a binary file

Tags: c

I want to write a array containing 16bit integers as raw binary to a file and have tried with the following example:

```
#  define __int8_t_defined
__intN_t (8, __QI__);
__intN_t (16, __HI__);
__intN_t (32, __SI__);
__intN_t (64, __DI__);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * rawf;
    rawf = fopen("./rawPcm","wb");
    int16_t buff[] = {0,0,0};
    fwrite(buff,sizeof(int16_t), sizeof(buff),rawf);
    fwrite(buff,sizeof(int16_t), sizeof(buff),rawf);  
    fclose(rawf);
}
```

However, the output contains more than just zeros.

```
$ hexdump -v rawPcm 
0000000 0000 0000 0000 85fd 0804 0001 0000 0000
0000010 0000 85fd 0804 0001                    
0000018
```

It writes `0000 0000 0000 85fd 0804 0001` for every `fwrite(buff,sizeof(int16_t), sizeof(buff),rawf);` while I would expect to get only `0000 0000 0000`.

What does the additional data represent `85fd 0804 0001` and how do I prevent it from occurring?

Comment: (Almost) minimal and complete example, observed output, expected output. You, sir, deserve a medal. :-D

Comment: Good old buffer overrun :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What does the additional data represent `85fd 0804 0001`

Possibly some random garbage data.

> how do I prevent it from occurring?

`fwrite(buff,sizeof(int16_t), sizeof(buff),rawf);` should be written as:

```
fwrite(buff,sizeof(int16_t), sizeof(buff) / sizeof(buff[0]),rawf);
/*               ^                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      */
/*       size of each object      Count of objects               */
/*              (2)                  (3)                         */

/* or */
fwrite(buff, sizeof buf[0], sizeof buff / sizeof buff[0], rawf);
```

`sizeof buff / sizeof buff[0]` gets the [array length in number of objects (or members)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) while `sizeof buff` gives the size of array in bytes.

So you are reading past the `buff` and writing it to the file and invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In your case you are seeing the random garbage data being written to output file.

In your case, `sizeof` of each element in `buff` is 2 bytes and `buff` array has 3 members causing total size to be 6 bytes. When you write `fwrite(buff,sizeof(int16_t), sizeof(buff),rawf);`, 6 objects of 2 byte each are written to the file which is not something that you want to do.

Now you are writing 6 data of type (size) `int16_t` starting from `buff[0]` i.e. `buff[0..5]` to the output. `buff[0..2]` are `0`s as expected and `buff[3..5]` are garbage.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `sizeof(buff[0])` for the element size argument too?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes, that is preferable.

Answer (score 9):

The third argument of `fwrite` is the *number* of elements of size specified by the second parameter. It is not the total size in bytes, which you are currently doing.

So you are overrunning your buffer.